# Show child group totals in parent group

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, bids

I have a report with has 4 groups.The groups listed by hierarchy are:

```
member name
plan
status
open/closed
```

I need to show all the details at the member level together and after the details I need to show the totals for open/closed, status, plan, member.

I will try to give some outline of how report should look like.

```
Member1
name  plan   joined_date status open/closed term_date amount_paid amount_due
john  plan1  04/02/15  Approved open  10/16/2018  20045.00  1045.00
kate  plan1  04/02/15  paid     closed 10/16/2018 1080.00   1080.00
charles plan1 04/02/15 paid open 10/16/2018 11956.00 956.00
smith plan2 04/02/15 denied closed 10/16/2018 2500.00 0.00
thomas plan2 04/02/15 approved open 10/16/2018 34590.00 1590.00

Plan1  number of details:3
approved/open  number of details:1   20045.00   1045.00
paid/open   number of details:1   11956.00   956.00
paid/closed   number of details:1   1080.00   1080.00
denied/closed   number of details:0  0.00  0.00

Plan2  number of details:2
approved/open  number of details:1   34590.00  1590.00
paid/open   number of details:0
paid/closed   number of details:0
denied/closed   number of details:1   2500.00   0.00

total for member1 number of details:5  110,000.00  89,987.60
```

There are only 4 variations of status/open/closed as defined in the totals. But there can be multiple plans and multiple members.

I cannot have totals for status and plans in middle of details.

Comment: That is a broad topic.   What specific part of it are you stuck on?

Comment: I am able to print status and plan totals at the end of the particular group.That means it prints totals in the middle of the details, i want to print all the details of the child groups and print totals of child groups in parent group. I am not able to print them on the parent group as now they are out of scope

Comment: How did you attempt to do it, and what error did you get?

Comment: Tried using expression RunningValue(Fields!ID.Value,sum,"STATUS_GROUP") In MEMBER_GROUP. gave error because it is not in scope

Comment: How about adding the data that you need to the Member dataset, so that you don't have to go out of scope to calculate the running value?

Comment: That data is part of member dataset. But the running value i need to calculate is the total for inner group. So, Member has two many plans in need to calculate totals for each one of them. each member has 4 combinations of status and open/closed. i need to calculate the total for them too. I know running value calculates total for the group that is in scope or for the whole dataset. how to get the total based on a inner group? I need to first calculate number of plans which i can do with running value in member group. But, how to calculate, store and print totals for each plan?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out.
I removed child groups plan status and open/closed for the details and added new table with groups plan, status and open/closed. Added Total for the details row of new table and hide the details rows.